# Get image Properties in iPhone to check image quality

Tags: ios, image, image-processing

I'm capturing an image from the iPhone camera and storing it in the document folder for further check and use.

Before storing the image i want to check the image quality based on the RGB value, grayscale and white balance , etc.

All that i can get from the image. But i am not able to understand what should or how should i use any framework that would help me retrieve this information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This app may do what you want. It is called Photo Metadata Reader. I saw it had RGB in the screenshots.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-metadata-reader/id437865801?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve metadata from UIImage - check this

https://github.com/foundry/UIImageMetadata

If you want to get, for example, color balance, I think you must get pixel data from image and compute this by yourself